# Linux : Rename file by a part the folder directory and move file

Tags: python, linux, bash, command-line, sh

I've seen a lot of very interesting things, but I can't do what I want.

I am using pyload to download files.
all downloads are saved in a download folder

So, i would like to create a script that would recover part of the name of the folder that will create me during the download to rename the file inside without modify the extension of file.

I'm talking about part of the file because the other part of the file will be used to know where should I move this file

here is a concrete example

```
/path/folder/Download/Powershell--SCCM--Add Auto Package/myfile.ps1
/path/folder/Download/Movies--TrailerofApplication/mymoooovie.mkv
/path/folder/Download/Music--Free--Personal--Mymusicname/mysicmu.mp3
```

For the first example :

```
/path/folder/Download/Powershell--SCCM--Add Auto Package/myfile.ps1
```

Powershell is a var. So Powershell = /my/path/powershell/
Same for moovies or Music with a different path.
Moovies by example is  /path/very/long/and/more/movies/here/

The -- is a separator.
The next is only folder inside the first folder.
Example :

```
    /path/folder/Download/Music--Free--Personal--Mymusicname/mysicmu.mp3
```

Is : /path/to/my/musics/Free/Personal/

The last var is name of file to need to edit.
Example :

```
    /path/folder/Download/Movies--TrailerofApplication/mymoooovie.mkv
```

Is :     /path/very/long/and/more/movies/here/TrailerofApplication.mkv

For the moment, all my multiple code is not work. 
I leave it to you because I don't know what type of language I can use to make it as simple as possible I would like to integrate to the pyload thereafter so that it is directly processed by the application.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this step by step:

1. Remove download folder path from the file path: `"/path/folder/Download/Powershell--SCCM--Add Auto Package/myfile.ps1" => "Powershell--SCCM--Add Auto Package/myfile.ps1"`
2. Get extension: `"Powershell--SCCM--Add Auto Package/myfile.ps1" => "ps1"`
3. Get target path string: `"Powershell--SCCM--Add Auto Package/myfile.ps1" => "Powershell--SCCM--Add Auto Package"`
4. From target path construct a list for finding and replacing path substitutions: `"Powershell--SCCM--Add Auto Package" => ["Powershell", "SCCM", "Add Auto Package"]`
5. Perform substitutions based on some dictionary: `["Powershell", "SCCM", "Add Auto Package"] => ["/my/path/powershell", "SCCM/path", "Add Auto Package"]` This can be done for all elements of the list or all excluding the last element just to be safe.
6. Create target path from the list and extension: `["/my/path/powershell", "SCCM/path", "Add Auto Package"] + "ps1"=> "/my/path/powershell/SCCM/path/Add Auto Package.ps1"`
7. Finally move the file, `shutil.move()` method can be for this.

Python can take care of this pretty easily, bash will be a bit harder. Also you want to integrate with *pyload* so Python may be better. Here is how the above algorithm looks in code in my Python shell (of course needs some editing for proper substitutions and such):

```
>>> import shutil
>>> 
>>> substitutions = {"Powershell": "/my/path/powershell", "SCCM": "SCCM/path"}
>>> source_path = "/path/folder/Download/Powershell--SCCM--Add Auto Package/myfile.ps1"
>>> extension = source_path.split(".")[1]
>>> print extension
ps1
>>> relative_path = source_path.replace("/path/folder/Download/", "")
>>> print relative_path
Powershell--SCCM--Add Auto Package/myfile.ps1
>>> destination_path_string = relative_path.split("/")[0]
>>> print destination_path_string
Powershell--SCCM--Add Auto Package
>>> destination_path_list = destination_path_string.split("--")
>>> print destination_path_list
['Powershell', 'SCCM', 'Add Auto Package']
>>> for i, p in enumerate(destination_path_list[:-1]):
    if p in substitutions:
        destination_path_list[i] = substitutions[p]


>>> print destination_path_list
['/my/path/powershell', 'SCCM/path', 'Add Auto Package']
>>> destination_path = "/".join(destination_path_list) + "." + extension
>>> print destination_path
/my/path/powershell/SCCM/path/Add Auto Package.ps1
>>> shutil.move(source_path, destination_path)
```